Relationship between Similarity score and Gain in XGBoost
I am trying to understand the intuition behind similarity scores and gain in XGBoost.
The similarity score is calculated as:

   \[
   \text{Similarity Score} = \frac{\text{(Sum of Residuals)}^2}{\text{Count of Residuals + regularization}} 
   \]

My understanding would be that if there is less bias, then the sum of residuals would be small. Hence a lower similarity score would be better. 

Then we go on to do a split and calculate similarity score for each node. In order to find the threshold, we use


   \[
   \text{Gain} = \text{similarity_left + similarity_right - similarity_root}
   \]


Then we pick the highest gain threshold. Here is where I struggle. Wouldn't higher similarity mean there is more bias? 

What exactly is the intuition behind the similarity score and gain? 

OK. I read more articles and the text says goals is to group "clusters of similar values". In which case the similarity score would be high. So we want higher similarity score.
